# $(this).val() does not return value of value-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the `value`-attribute of my `<a>`-tag, which is in the below example `999`. See my minimum viable example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Jquery Modal</title>
</head>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //display modal form for product EDIT ***************************
    $(document).on('click', '.open_modal', function() {
      var cryptos_id = $(this).val();
      console.log("cryptos_id: " + cryptos_id)
    });

  });
</script>

<body>
  <div>
    <tr>
      <a id="coo99" value="999" class="open_modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <sup> EDIT</sup>
      </a>
    </tr>
  </div>

  <!-- MODAL SECTION -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="frmProducts" name="frmProducts" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">
            <div class="form-group error">
              <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Country of Origin" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" value="update">Edit Entry</button>
          <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="101">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

When you press the `EDIT` button `crypto_id` returns currently nothing, however I would like to get the `value`- attribute - `999` - of my `a`-tag back.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Comment: .val() is used for form fields mostly. you want the value of the attribute 'value' so do this: var cryptos_id = $(this).attr('value');

Comment: Well, `value` is not a legal attribute of an anchor. It's that simple.

Comment: While not 'legal', it is valid -- but as @MarouenMhiri says, simply use `.attr('value'); ` to get to it.

Comment: @Snowmonkey Valid and legal mean the same thing. [It's not valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). `value` is only applicable to form fields.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, you're right. Its evidence of my history of seat-of-the-pants coding that I have gotten used to custom attributes being whatever, but that is invalid -- that's the point of the `data-*` attribute space. Apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values only pertain to form field elements. You'd need to use a data attribute instead:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.open_modal', function() {
  var cryptos_id = $(this).data('value');
  console.log("cryptos_id: " + cryptos_id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="coo99" class="open_modal" href="#" data-value="999" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>
```

Comment: what are *"input attributes"*?

Comment: Sorry. Meant to just say inputs.

Comment: figured so... *"form controls"* is a helpful term for them also

Comment: Values also apply to `textarea`, `option` and `datalist` elements. It's best to just say `values` only apply to form fields, which encompasses all of them.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Good thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the wrong thing.

`$(this).val()` won't give you what you're after, you need to use something like `$(this).attr("value")` instead. This will grab any content defined in the attribute "value".

(`.val()` is mainly used in forms, i.e. with `input` entities).

Comment: This wont help I'm afraid. Like gforce301 mentioned value is not a valid attribute for an a-tag. You should use the data thing suggested by Carl.

Comment: @HansDash you can put almost any attribute on almost any tag and use `attr` to get it `value` isn't that special.

Comment: @HansDash It's not "valid" no, but it "works". The other answers here cover why a "value" attribute isn't correct.

Comment: @Musa You can also make up your own elements and find them in the DOM, but that's also invalid and something that isn't done.

Comment: @ScottMarcus hmm... [`angular`](https://angularjs.org/#create-components)

Comment: @Musa We're not talking about Angular, which translates custom markup to valid markup.